# Can I plug my Iomega hard drive into my new BT Home Hub and access the tunes stored in it from my MacBook Pro wirelessly?

Tags: itunes, network, hard-drive

We have just acquired a BT home Hub router which has a USB socket. I have my music stored in an Iomega hard drive and normally plug this into the MacBook, which is a bit clumsy. ( I have told iTunes where to find my music when I am logged in. My partner uses the Mac to store her music.)

I was hoping to be able to plug the Iomega into the Home Hub which would send the music to the Mac (or indeed iPad) wherever it is in the house.

Does anyone know if this is possible and where I'd start; or should I just ring BT?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect a USB hard disk to the home hub, and access it as an SMB network drive. There are instructions on the [BT website](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11379/~/why-is-there-a-usb-port-on-the-back-of-my-bt-home-hub?).

You would be able to open your iTunes library from the network drive, but the home hub doesn't have an iTunes server built in (or at least the v2 I have doesn't, and I can't see any mention of it in the v3 features) so it won't appear as a shared library in iTunes.

Make sure the drive is formatted to Fat32 and it's basically plug and play.